# I Ran startx From Terminal as SU Now I Can't Log In

Tags: command-line, xorg, login

I ran startx while in SU mode from terminal while already logged into Ubuntu desktop. This was probably really stupid, I know. The screen immediately went completely black. I rebooted, now every time I go to log in the screen flashes black for a second then takes me back to the login screen. I tried the [solution here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2190818) but that did not work for me as it did not regenerate the .ICEconfig file, now the file is just gone and I still can't log in. Guest account works fine. I can't find any other information on this subject. Please don't let me have to go back to Windows guys. I need some help here.

Comment: are you able to login in recovery mode? (holding LEFT SHIFT, or ESC at boot)

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue with the above linked solution. I was originally applying the solution to the .ICEconfig file found at /root/.ICEconfig, however I should have applied it to the one found at ~/.ICEconfig. Once I applied it to the correct file, everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: @JtheDude:  Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: Yes, I definitely will put it up as an answer, I'm at school right now but I will consider it a homework assignment for today ;-)

Comment: I finally got an answer up, hope it's a decent one and I can get an upvote! Apologies for the delay I have been busy with school and other things have kept coming up.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what happened is that invoking the `startx` command as a super user changed ownership of the `.Xauthority` file to root. `.Xauthority` is a 'magic cookie' file that authenticates clients requesting access to the X display server. What that means is that when you first log in, the X display server needs to authenticate your identity before it gives you access to the X Window system, i.e. your desktop. A more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization), while the solution I found can be found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2190818).

What worked for me was using `CTRL + ALT + F1` from the login screen to get to a terminal, login from the terminal, and then:
`sudo chown user:user ~/.Xauthority` where `user:user` is your username followed by a colon, then your username again. If that seems complicated or doesn't work for some reason, you can just delete the file altogether using `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority` and from now on you can just do everything from the command line. I'm just kidding it will regenerate the file when required and the new file will have the correct permissions.

Hope this helps as the issue made me panic at first but turned out to be a relatively simple fix, and I learned a little bit about how display servers work in the process.

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers that didn't get any upvotes...  So finally you got one!  ;-)